# Relationship between char and ASCII Code?

Tags: c

My computer science teacher taught us that which data type to declare depends on the size of the value for a variable you need. And then he demonstrated having a char add and subtract a number to output a different char. I remember he said this is something to do with ASCII Code. Can anyone explain this more specifically and clearly ? So, is char considerd as a number(since we can do math with it ) or a character or both? Can we print out the number behind a char?how?

Comment: `char c = 'A';  printf("%c %d", c, c);` See if this proves illuminating.

Comment: It depends on how you use it. A number is a number, a character is a representation of that number given a certain encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is char considerd as a number or a character or both?

Both. It is an integer, but that integer value represents a character, as described by the character encoding of your system. The character encoding of the system that your computer science teacher uses happens to be ASCII.

> Can we print out the number behind a char?how?

C++ (as the question used to be tagged):

The behaviour of the character output stream (such as `std::cout`) is to print the represented character when you insert an integer of type `char`. But the behaviour for all other integer types is to print the integer value. So, you can print the integer value of a `char` by converting it to another integer type:

```
std::cout << (unsigned)'c';
```

C:

There are no templated output streams, so you don't need to do explicit conversion to another integer (except for the signedness). What you need is the correct format specifier for `printf`:

```
printf("%hhu", (unsigned char)'c');
```

`hh` is for integer of size `char`, `u` is to for unsigned as you probably are interested in the unsigned representation.

Comment: Note your last example could have unexpected results if `char` is signed and `'c'` has a "negative" codepoint (not the case with ASCII). I don't find an online compiler exhibiting this, but the following code `signed char x = (unsigned char)200; printf("%hhu\n", x); printf("%hhu\n", (unsigned char)x);` compiled with MinGW on windows outputs `65480 200`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen user2079303 used a _character constant_ of 1 character.  IIRC, they are always a positive `int`.

Comment: @chux I can't find this assertion. Have a look at `§6.4.4.4`, no 10 -- shouldn't it be mentioned there? (or, alternatively, in `§5.2.1` describing character sets?)

Comment: "character encoding of the system that your computer science teacher uses happens to be ASCII"—more likely a character encoding that is a superset of ASCII. ASCII itself is seldom used. See "execution character set" in the compiler documentation ([gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html)) and then look how the program is built.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I neither have found a spec to support [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104764/relationship-between-char-and-ascii-code/45104867?noredirect=1#comment77184210_45104867).  Hmmm.

Comment: @chux yes, found it myself through a recent interesting question on it :) not the most obvious section to look for this info. Thanks though, good to know signedness isn't an issue with character constants.

Answer (score 3):

A `char` can hold a number, it's the smallest integer type available on your machine and must have *at least* 8 bits. It is synonymous to a *byte*.

It's *typical* use is to store the codes of characters. Computers can only deal with numbers, so, to represent characters, numbers are used. Of course you must agree on which number means which character.

C doesn't require a specific *character encoding*, but most systems nowadays use a superset of ASCII (this is a very old encoding using only 7 bits) like e.g. UTF-8.

So, if you have a `char` that holds a character and you add or subtract some value, the result will be another number that happens to be the code for a *different* character.

In ASCII, the characters `0`-`9`, `a`-`z` and `A`-`Z` have adjacent code points, therefore by adding e.g. 2 to `A`, the result will be `C`.

> Can we print out the number behind a char?

Of course. It just depends whether you *interpret* the value in the `char` as just a number or as the code of a character. E.g. with `printf`:

```
printf("%c\n", 'A');                   // prints the character
printf("%hhu\n", (unsigned char)'A');  // prints the number of the code
```

The cast to `(unsigned char)` is only needed because `char` is allowed to be either signed or unsigned, we want to treat it as unsigned here.

Comment: Don't know if you feel this is worth mention, but the Standard requires that `0`-`9` be encoded in a contiguous sequence, allowing the useful `int num = x - '0';` idiom to be used portably.

Comment: @DavidBowling I think it's a *very worthwhile* comment, but maybe I'll leave it out of my answer, which might be confusing enough to a beginner already ;)

Answer (score 3):

A `char` takes up a single byte.  On systems with an 8 bit byte this gives it a range (assuming `char` is signed) of -128 to 127.  You can print this value as follows:

```
char a = 65;
printf("a=%d\n", a);
```

Output:

```
65
```

The `%d` format specifier prints its argument as a decimal integer.  If on the other hand you used the `%c` format specifier, this prints the character associated with the value.  On systems that use [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), that means it prints the ASCII character associated with that number:

```
char a = 65;
printf("a=%c\n", a);
```

Output:

```
A
```

Here, the character `A` is printed because 65 is the ASCII code for `A`.

You can perform arithmetic on these numbers and print the character for the resulting code:

```
char a = 65;
printf("a=%c\n", a);
a = a + 1;
printf("a=%c\n", a);
```

Output:

```
A
B
```

In this example we first print `A` which is the ASCII character with code 65.  We then add 1 giving us 66.  Then we print the ASCII character for 66 which is `B`.

Answer (score 2):

Every variable is stored in binary (i.e as a number,)  `char`s, are just numbers of a specific size.

They represent a character when encoded using some character encoding, the ASCII standard ([www.asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com)) is here.

As in the [@Igor comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104764/relationship-between-char-and-ascii-code#comment77180585_45104764), if you run the following code; you see the ASCII character, Decimal and Hexadecimal representation of your `char`.

```
char c = 'A'; 
printf("%c %d 0x%x", c, c, c);
```

Output:

> A 65 0x41

As an exercise to understand it better, you could make a program to generate the ASCII Table yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> My computer science teacher taught us that which data type to declare depends on the size of the value for a variable you need.

This is correct.  Different types can represent different ranges of values.  For reference, here are the various integral types and the *minimum* ranges they must be able to represent:

```
Type                             Minimum Range
----                             -------------
signed char                       -127...127
unsigned char                        0...255
char                same as signed or unsigned char, depending on implementation
short                           -32767...32767
unsigned short                       0...65535
int                             -32767...32767
unsigned int                         0...65535
long                       -2147483647...2147483647
unsigned long                        0...4294967295
long long         -9223372036854775807...9223372036854775807
unsigned long long                   0...18446744073709551615
```

An implementation may represent a larger range in a given type; for example, on most modern implementations, the range of an `int` is the same as the range of a `long`.

C doesn't mandate a fixed size (bit width) for the basic integral types (although unsigned types are the same size as their signed equivalent); at the time C was first developed, byte and word sizes could vary between architectures, so it was easier to specify a minimum range of values that the type had to represent and leave it to the implementor to figure out how to map that onto the hardware.

C99 introduced the `stdint.h` header, which defines fixed-width types like `int8_t` (8-bit), `int32_t` (32-bit), etc., so you can define objects with specific sizes if necessary.

> So, is char considerd as a number(since we can do math with it ) or a character or both?

`char` is an integral data type that can represent values in *at least* the range `[0...127]`<sup>1</sup>, which is the range of encodings for the *basic execution character set* (upper- and lowercase Latin alphabet, decimal digits `0` through `9`, and common punctuation characters).  It can be used for storing and doing regular arithmetic on small integer values, but that's not the typical use case.

You can print `char` objects out as a characters or numeric values:

```
#include <limits.h> // for CHAR_MAX
...
printf( "%5s%5s\n", "dec", "char" );
printf( "%5s%5s\n", "---", "----" );

for ( char i = 0; i < CHAR_MAX; i++ )
{
  printf("%5hhd%5c\n", i, isprint(i) ? i : '.' );
}
```

That code will print out the integral value and the associated character, like so (this is ASCII, which is what my system uses):

```
...
65    A
66    B
67    C
68    D
69    E
70    F
71    G
72    H
73    I 
...
```

Control characters like `SOH` and `EOT` don't have an associated printing character, so for those value the code above just prints out a `'.'`.

By definition, a `char` object takes up a single *storage unit* (byte); the number of bits in a single storage unit must be *at least* 8, but could be more.

---

1. Plain `char` may be either signed or unsigned depending on the implementation so it can represent additional values outside that range, but it must be able to represent *at least* those values.