# Do 'a' and '0' always have positive values even if char is signed?

Tags: c, character-encoding, language-lawyer

Depending on the environment and compiler settings, the type `char` can be signed or unsigned by default, which means the range of values for single character constants on 8-bit 2s complement systems can be either `-128..127` or `0..255`.

In the ubiquitous ASCII character set, its ISO-8859-X extensions or the UTF-8 encoding, upper- and lowercase letters as well as digits have values below 127.

But such is not the case with the [EBCDIC character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC):

`'A'` is 0xC1, `'a'` is 0x81 and `'1'` is 0xF1.

Since these value are above 127, does it mean the type `char` must be unsigned on 8-bit EBCDIC systems?  Or can `'a'`, `'A'`  and `'1'` have negative values?

What about other character sets? Can the letters or digits ever have negative values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: not a duplicate at all. I'm asking something much more precise than the question in reference.

Comment: chars are either signed or unsigned. If they're unsigned, then they're always positive. If not, then char values with the top bit set are negative.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage:  I am well aware of this regrettable fact.  I'm asking if we can always assume `'a' > 0`, especially on EBCDIC systems where `'a'` has the 8-bit encoding `1000 0001`.

Comment: @chqrlie "basic execution character .... guaranteed to be nonnegative.". was the cite I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104764/relationship-between-char-and-ascii-code/45104867#comment77184210_45104867).  Nice Q & A.

Comment: @chux: thank you for the suggestion.  This question was too subtile for a Saturday evening I guess.

Comment: @Peter: the point of this question is exactly this! There is such a guarantee in the C Standard, and has been for a while. See the accepted answer for details.  Also `char` values and character constants outside the execution character set should be cast to `(unsigned char)` when passed to `isalpha()`, `isalnum()`... because these functions have undefined behavior for negative values (except `EOF`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[C99 states](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.2.5.html) that:

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> An object declared as type char is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set.
>
> If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative.

Thus, if the machine in question uses EBCDIC encoding and 8-bit `char`, then the C99 compliant compiler designed for this machine must have plain `char` be unsigned.

Comment: More precisely: if the machine in question has 8-bit chars and uses EBCDIC encoding, then the C99 compliant compiler designed for this machine must use unsigned char-s by default.

Comment: @chqrlie any system must offer `unsigned char`,  you mean to say that plain `char` should be unsigned . Plain char is a distinct type from `unsigned char` so I think it is confusing to use the term `unsigned char` to mean plain char being unsigned.

Comment: also, C11 5.2.1/3 defines the *basic execution character set* to include `'a'` and `'0'`

Comment: FYI, very similar wording appeared in C90: "An object declared as type char is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set.  If a member of the required source character set enumerated in $2.2.1 is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be positive." per https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sMhqRXLYNQ0J:flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us