# merging of two character constants in c

Tags: c

I want to merge two single character constants into one like '1'+'2'='12'.So that I can add an integer value to this single character.
I have tried a lot of things like used their ASCII values.Also the substring functions doesn't seem to work in this context.Help!

Comment: It would be good to show us your effort so far. but something like `char arr[3] = {0}, arr[0] = '1', arr[1] = '2', arr[2] = 0;` But this is now string.

Comment: `12` isn't a character though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the number from 2 digit characters, the formula is very simple:

```
char c1 = '1';
char c2 = '2';
int value = (c1 - '0') * 10 + (c2 - '0');  // value is 12
```

`c1 - '0'` evaluates to the number represented by the digit `c1`. It works because the digits are guaranteed to be consecutive from `'0'` to `'9'` in the execution character set.

Answer (score 0):

There are more 'beautiful' ways to do it, but this ought to be enough for a first attempt.

```
int value = 0;

if (firstcharacter == '1') value = 10;
if (firstcharacter == '2') value = 20;
/* ... */
if (firstcharacter == '9') value = 90;

if (secondcharacter == '1') value += 1;
/* ... */
if (secondcharacter == '9') value += 9;

printf("value + 42 is %d.\n", value + 42);
```

Comment: Your way is waay not that beautiful. Check this: `if (fc >= '1' && fc <= '9') value = 10 * (fc - '0');` And then, `if (sc >= '1' && sc <= '9') value += sc - '0'`. `fc` means `first character`, `sc` means `second character`.

Comment: This seems helpful but way too like static.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to combine two `char`s which are digits to form an integer value that can be used in arithmetic expressions, then a compound literal can be used to form a string from the `char`s, and `strtol()` can be used to convert the string to an integer value. Here is an example that uses the function `char_digits_int()` to convert a pair of `char` inputs into an `int` value. If either of the arguments is not a digit, `-1` is returned:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int char_digits_int(char x, char y);

int main(void)
{
    char a = '1';
    char b = '2';

    printf("%c and %c form: %d\n", a, b, char_digits_int(a, b));
    printf("The sum of %c%c and 1 is: %d\n",
           a, b, char_digits_int(a, b) + 1);

    int value = char_digits_int('0', 'x');
    if (value == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Non-digit input\n");
    } else {
        printf("Value: %d\n", value);
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Returns -1 if x or y is not a digit */
int char_digits_int(char x, char y)
{
    int val = -1;

    if (isdigit((unsigned char) x) && isdigit((unsigned char) y)) {
        val = strtol((char []) { x, y, '\0' }, NULL, 10);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Program output:

```
1 and 2 form: 12
The sum of 12 and 1 is: 13
Non-digit input
```

Comment: for 2 characters ? Anonymous compound literals?  The OP asked the **elementary** question, give him answer he will understand. He definitely is the beginer

Comment: @PeterJ-- compound literals are a fundamental feature of the language that everyone should know about. If OP doesn't know about them yet, now is a good time to learn.

Comment: If you ask 20 people claiming they know C I bet 10 never heard about them :). And another 7 will struggle to write a correct one without the access to internet.

Comment: I am right - see the answer chosen - the one OP actually understands

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to combine the character constants `'1'` and `'2'` to get the value of the multi-character character constant `'12'`, the answer is *There is no portable way to do this* and you should probably not write code that uses these things anyway.

Look at this answer for a historical perspective on this oddity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576458/4593267

It you are still curious (good for you), here is a test case:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    if ((('1' << CHAR_BIT) | '2') == '12')
        printf("(('1' << CHAR_BIT) | '2') == '12'\n");
    else
    if ((('2' << CHAR_BIT) | '1') == '12')
        printf("(('2' << CHAR_BIT) | '1') == '12'\n");
    else
        printf("No simple way to get '12' from '1' and '2'\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, I get these warnings:

```
multichar.c:5:38: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    if ((('1' << CHAR_BIT) | '2') == '12')
                                     ^
multichar.c:8:38: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    if ((('2' << CHAR_BIT) | '1') == '12')
                                     ^
multichar.c:8:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
    if ((('2' << CHAR_BIT) | '1') == '12')
          ^~~
multichar.c:9:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        printf("(('2' << CHAR_BIT) | '1') == '12'\n");
        ^~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
```

And this output:

```
(('1' << CHAR_BIT) | '2') == '12'
```

But other systems, notably big endian ones, may produce a different output.

Comment: Interesting link; is endianness the only implementation-defined aspect of multi-character constants? Also, on a pedantic note, isn't it possible for a character constant, e.g., `'1'`, to have a negative value, leading to UB with left bit-shifts?

Comment: @DavidBowling: Endianness is the main aspect, but the Standard allows for other implementation-defined choices.  Regarding the negative characters, the Standard does mandate that the digits and letters have positive values as confirmed by the responses to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123003/do-a-and-0-always-have-positive-values-even-if-char-is-signed

Comment: Thanks for that link; I had forgotten about the caveat for members of the basic execution character set....